# How to correctly zoom in MapKit on iOS17

Tags: ios, swiftui, mapkit

When using MKCoordinateRegion,  in iOS 17, I am not getting the zoom level to set correctly.  It is always staying tightly zoomed to the 1 place being passed to my view.

I would expect it to have a zoom level of 6.9 miles or 11km square given my MKCoordinateSpan of 0.1

This is on iOS17 utilizing Xcode 15.0.1

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

/// a very simple view that just presents a  Map given a MKCoordinateRegion
struct MapView: View {

    struct Place: Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        let name: String
        var latitude: Double
        var longitude: Double
        var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
            CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        }
    }
    
    @State private var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    var places = [
        Place(name: "", latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0  )
    ]
    
    init(region: MKCoordinateRegion) {
        self.region = region
        self.region.span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: CLLocationDegrees(0.1), longitudeDelta: CLLocationDegrees(0.1))
        places[0].longitude = region.center.longitude
        places[0].latitude = region.center.latitude
    }

    var body: some View {
        Map  {
            Annotation (
                "\(places[0].name)",
                coordinate: places[0].coordinate,
                anchor: .bottom
            ) {
                Image(systemName: "house")
                    .padding(4)
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .cornerRadius(4)
            }
        }
        .mapStyle(.standard(elevation: .realistic))
        .onMapCameraChange { context in
            region = context.region
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not passing the `MKCoordinateRegion` region to the `Map` view.   The only item you're passing to it is the annotation, so it is centering the map on that.

Comment: That's because passing `MKCoordinateRegion` is deprecated in iOS 17.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a region to drive a `Map` view was depreciated in iOS 17 in favour of the new `MapBuilder` approach.  However if you want to take this approach you need to bind the `Map` to the `MKCoordinateRegion` and then pass in the annotations.  You also need to use a type for your annotation that conforms to the MapAnnotationProtocol (`Annotation` doesn't).  Both of these are issue in your sample code.

Rewriting your view to bind to the `region` property you've created and using the basic built-in `MapAnnotation` (which was also depreciated in favour of a `MapContentBuilder`) gives a working solution of:

```
 var body: some View {
      Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: places) { place in
         MapAnnotation(coordinate: place.coordinate) { 
            VStack {
               Image(systemName: "house")
                  .padding(4)
                  .foregroundStyle(.white)
                  .background(Color.green)
                  .cornerRadius(4)
               Text(place.name)
            }
         }
      }
      .mapStyle(.standard(elevation: .realistic))
      .onMapCameraChange { context in
         region = context.region
      }
   }
```

However you'd be better off investigating the newer `MapBuilder` and `MapContentBuilder` APIs if you can target iOS17 and later as the map functionality is greatly enhanced.

Comment: Got it, that did the trick, will investigate conversion to MapBuilder / MapContentBuilder approach.

Comment: @MichaelRowe ti would be helpful if you could mark it as the accepted answer too.